React: call onChange hook initially, the same time defaultChecked is set

let radio_onchange = (e) => {
    variable.radio = radio_name;
    if (on_update) on_update();
};

let radio_defaultChecked = variable_index === radio_index;

return (
    <Fragment key={radio_index}>        <input type='radio'               name={radio_id + '-' + radio_name}
               value={radio_name}
               defaultChecked={radio_defaultChecked}
               onChange={radio_onchange}
        />    </Fragment>);



On change, the radio button has a side effect, which is setting variable.radio to radio_name.
Now defaultChecked only sets checked of the radio initially, that is when the component first mounts.
I also want to trigger onchange's side effect just at that moment, when it initially loads.
I could use something like useEffect with no dependencies, but the code above is two loops deep (iterating over n variables and k radios) so when I use useEffect just below radio_defaultChecked to call radio_onchange, that throws some errors like
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by VariableForm. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

What would be the best way to resolve this? To extract each (variable, radio) tuple into its own component which uses useEffect to only initially set variable.radio?

I see 2 options for you:

find a way to make all the calls in a global useEffect at the root of your component. It is for me the cleanest way.
if you really can't, you can extract your input and all the logic inside your loop in a dedicated component so it can have its own useEffect.


cant give you an upvote because i don't have enough rep, but thanks for your answer

I think you can still mark this answer as the one solving your issue ;)
